# Merge query, mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My documents:

```
    var docA = {
      placeId: 1,
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A'
        },
        {
          name: 'B'
        }
      ]
    };

    var docB = {
      placeId: 1,
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A'
        },
        {
          name: 'C'
        }
      ]
    };
```

Output after query:

```
    {
      placeId: 1,
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A'
        },
        {
          name: 'B'
        },
        {
          name: 'C'
        }
      ]
    };
```

So all documents that have the same placeId should be merged to one. The `items` arr should also be merged and all duplicates should be removed.

This should be saved.

Can this be done in a single query? Or do I need to loops?

Comment: You can try `db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$items"},{"$group":{_id:"$placeId", items:{$addToSet:"$items"}}})`

Comment: Np. Use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) after group.

Comment: An nice, $out. Didn't know about that one. I'll try it out. Thx.